# Spring OAuth2: DuplicateKeyException when using JdbcTokenStore and DefaultTokenServices under heavy load

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

As mentioned in the title, I'm experiencing the issue, when the same client is querying the token endpoint concurrently (two processes requesting token for the same client at the same time).

The message in the logs of the auth server looks like this:

```
2016-12-05 19:08:03.313  INFO 31717 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: DuplicateKeyException, PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "oauth_access_token_pkey"
      Detail: Key (authentication_id)=(4148f592d600ab61affc6fa90bcbf16f) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "oauth_access_token_pkey"
      Detail: Key (authentication_id)=(4148f592d600ab61affc6fa90bcbf16f) already exists.
```

I'm using PostgreSQL with table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_access_token
(
  token_id character varying(256),
  token bytea,
  authentication_id character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  user_name character varying(256),
  client_id character varying(256),
  authentication bytea,
  refresh_token character varying(256),
  CONSTRAINT oauth_access_token_pkey PRIMARY KEY (authentication_id)
)
```

And my application looks like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OAuthServTest {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run (OAuthServTest.class, args);
   }

   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

      @Autowired
      private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

      @Autowired
      private DataSource            dataSource;

      @Bean
      public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder ( ) {
         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder ( );
      }

      @Override
      public void configure (AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
         endpoints.authenticationManager (authenticationManager);
         endpoints.tokenServices (tokenServices ( ));
      }

      @Override
      public void configure (ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
         clients.jdbc (this.dataSource).passwordEncoder (passwordEncoder ( ));
      }

      @Override
      public void configure (AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
         oauthServer.passwordEncoder (passwordEncoder ( ));
      }

      @Bean
      public TokenStore tokenStore ( ) {
         return new JdbcTokenStore (this.dataSource);
      }

      @Bean
      @Primary
      public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices ( ) {
         final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices ( );
         defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore (tokenStore ( ));
         return defaultTokenServices;
      }

   }
}
```

My research always lead me to [this problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/276). But this bug was fixed a long time ago and I'm on the latest version of Spring Boot (v1.4.2).

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong and the retrieval of the token in [DefaultTokenServices](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.12.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java) is not happening in the transaction?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with a race condition on the `DefaultTokenServices`.

I found a workaround. Not saying it's gorgeous but it works. The idea is to add retry logic using an AOP Advice around the `TokenEndpoint`:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TokenEndpointRetryInterceptor {

  private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 4;

  @Around("execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.*(..))")
  public Object execute (ProceedingJoinPoint aJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    int tts = 1000;
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
      try {
        return aJoinPoint.proceed();
      } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        Thread.sleep(tts);
        tts=tts*2;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute: " + aJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I have the same error, why do I need this? I don't have in my spring boot application : `@Aspect`, `@Around` and `ProceedingJoinPoint`. How can I solve the same issue ?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1033

```
 @Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    final AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator = new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource) {

        @Override
        public void storeAccessToken(final OAuth2AccessToken token, final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            final String key = authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication);
            jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?", key);
            super.storeAccessToken(token, authentication);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: You can still get the `DuplicateKeyException` using this approach so it doesn't fix the problem entirely although it does make it happen less often.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have Spring and use plain JEE with EJBs, you may consider a database table level workaround for this. I created the following trigger to modify the duplicate authentication_id (and token) by appending the timestamp and a random string, so it will not fail and throw an exception. Not the ideal fix but does the job.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER handle_duplicate_authentication_id

BEFORE INSERT ON oauth_access_token
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  declare suffix varchar(20);
  SET suffix = CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 8));

  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oauth_access_token WHERE authentication_id = NEW.authentication_id)) THEN
        SET NEW.authentication_id = CONCAT(NEW.authentication_id, suffix);
  END IF;
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oauth_access_token WHERE token_id = NEW.token_id)) THEN
        SET NEW.token_id = CONCAT(NEW.token_id, suffix);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1033#issuecomment-771278779

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    final AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator = new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource) {
        @Override
        public void storeAccessToken(final OAuth2AccessToken token, final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            final String key = authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication);
            int row = jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?", key);
            if (row > 0) {
                super.storeAccessToken(token, authentication);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).